# Sqlalchemy pickle type storing more than needed in DB

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to store a python list of strings in my postgres database table like so:

["43193292, "1231321231"]

Models:

```
__workflows = Column('workflows', PickleType)
```

However when I commit to the DB, I end up with this:

77B
00000000  80 02 5D 71 01 28 55 13 34 33 31 39 33 32 39 32    ..]q.(U.**43193292**
....

I don't need the entire binary string, just the bolded part (**43193292**). Ideally I could serialize and deserialize with json dumps/loads.

Is it possible to do this? Thanks

Comment: Well, don't use pickle? Best way is to store it as [`varchar[]`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).

Comment: I haven't used sqlalchemy in a long time, but postgres does have `json` data types. If serializing to json is what you want, then check out [the `json` and `jsonb` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) and [their associated functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, using JSON type works perfect for serializing a python list of strings

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

__workflows = Column('workflows', JSON)
```